# How to remove scroll bar from browser window

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

How do i completely remove scroll bar from the browser window?
I know you are suppose to use overflow, But the overflow is being overridden.
I have no idea why is it being overridden. I tried other ways for the overflow.

My code:

```
  #column1 {
    background-color: #ffe6e6;
    list-style: none;
    border-width: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    left: 1%;
}

   #column2 {
    background-color: #ffe6e6;
    list-style: none;
    border-style: solid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    left: 2%;
}


 html,
   body {
   overflow:hidden
   }
```

Comment: you can not remove browser scroll its depend on your screen size

Comment: If you ask like this, how we can help you? You need to add your code where you are seeing the issue that browser is opening up with a scroll. There can be multiple reasons like screen size or overflow is getting overridden. So first you upload your code.

Comment: whats problem you get explain or share

Comment: hi all, it's being overridden

Comment: what overridden share your code

Comment: see my full css code.

Comment: paste html also

Comment: Html page:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/51c8b8f97a73774f257857f2659cbf2e and css page https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd148c08ca933b9c1b6669c1e65d58d7

Answer (score 4):

see this

Set `overflow: hidden;` on the body tag

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The code above hides both horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

If you want to hide only the vertical scrollbar, use overflow-y:

```
body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

And if you want to hide only the horizontal scrollbar, use overflow-x:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

and also for all

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and for ie 7

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Please ann some context to your answer. Why does it work opposed to what the quesrion asker did?

Comment: This will let the browser act like the scrollbar is still there. So you can use mouse wheel and all the other gestures to scroll around. The `overflow: hidden` method will prevent scrolling, instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to close the attribute with a semicolon, so it isn't being applied. Similar to other posts, it should look like this:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
html,
body {
   overflow:hidden
}
```